# Optimizing queries on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, cron, scalability

I have a fitness application that I am working on. I have integrated fitbit/garmin with it.

So the heart-rates data that I get from these vendors, are on a unix timestamp basis:

```
HEARTRATES COLLECTION

1614975688461 : 58BPM 
1614975688461 : 33BPM 
1614975688461 : 99BPM 
1614975688461 : 44BPM 
1614975688461 : 67BPM 
1614975688461 : 89BPM
```

I have a collection in my mongoDB, which maps each of these timestamps to the heartrate.

Now I plan on having a chart which shows the weekly, monthly and the yearly average of the heart-rate for that person.

Now to do this, I can always do a less than greater query on the timestamp in my db(span of 30 days for months and span of 365 days for the yearly plot), compute and get the average on the application and show. But my doubt is, will this scale for like a million users?

Alternation solution that I have in mind: Each time the person syncs their fitbit/garmin device, I run cronjobs at the end of each day which updates collections "Weekly" and "Yearly" for each user. This way all the app has to do is query the weekly collection for the weekly data starting from the query date or the yearly collection for the data starting from the query date.

```
WEEKLY COLLECTION : WHICH UPDATES EVERDAY:
DAY 1: 56BPM
DAY 2: 56BPM
DAY 3: 56BPM
DAY 4: 56BPM
DAY 5: 56BPM
DAY 6: 56BPM
DAY 7: 56BPM
```

Does the alternate solution make any sense or is it making things worse? If you have any better solution, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern

Comment: This is GOLD! Exactly what I had in mind. God bless you!